# Convert variables names to strings in Python 3

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that I would like to convert to a list of strings where the strings are the names of the variables. I would like to loop through the list and extract the length of the lists into one list and the name of the list into another. To illustrate here's an attempt to do it using str(variable), which obviously doesn't work because it converts the value of the variable, not the name. I'm trying to convert the name

```
# Here are the initial lists
common_nouns = ['noun', 'fact', 'banana']
verbs = ['run', 'jump']
adjectives = ['red', 'blue']
# Here is my list of lists:
parts_of_speech = [common_nouns, verbs, adjectives]
labels=[]
data=[]
for pos in parts_of_speech:
    if pos != []:
        labels.append(str(pos)) # This part doesn't work
        data.append(len(pos))
```

result:

```
labels = ["['noun', 'fact', 'banana']", "['run', 'jump']", "['red', 'blue']"]
```

desired result:

```
labels = ['common_nouns', 'verbs', 'adjectives']
```

EDIT: Added initial lists

Comment: so you're defining `common_nouns` etc elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the question to add that

Comment: This seems like a futile exercise. One simple solution. Wherever you are doing `parts_of_speech = [common_nouns, verbs, adjectives]` do `parts_of_speech = ["common_nouns", "verbs", "adjectives"]`. Since it is statically known what variables you are inserting.

Comment: In Python, a chunk of data can be referred to by several different variables. By the time you reach `str(pos)` the first time through the loop, several different variables point to the original contents of `common_nouns` (call it `cnc`, which is the actual memory holding `['noun', 'fact', 'banana']`), like this: common_nouns -> cnc, parts_of_speech[0] -> cnc, pos -> cnc. There's no straightforward way to look at `pos` and figure out that the thing it points to is also pointed to by a variable called `common_nouns`. As others point out, you'll do better to setup the right structures in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the opposite of the frequent question on how to have "variable variables". But the answer is exactly the same: don't do that, use a dict.

Store this data as a single dict with those values as the keys, then you can use the `.keys()` method to give you the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a dictionary as Daniel Roseman suggested. Here is the implementation:

```
parts_of_speech = [common_nouns, verbs, adjectives]
all_labels = ['common_nouns', 'verbs', 'adjectives']
pos_dict = dict(zip(all_labels, parts_of_speech))
labels=[]
data=[]
for pos, lst in pos_dict.items():
    if lst:
        data.append(len(lst))
        labels.append(pos)
```

Comment: You might try `for pos, lst in pos_dict.iteritems():`, then use `lst` instead of `my_dict[pos]` in the later code. It's also considered "Pythonic" to use `if lst:` instead of `if lst != []:`.